# Differencing a column in a data source

Tags: tableau-api, lag

I have a text file with two columns: "date" and "cumulative value". I'd like to difference "cumulative value", as a calculated field in the data source.

I cannot even get a lag value:lookup([cumulative value],-1) produces an error.

Thank you.

Comment: Are you trying to subtract "cumulative value" from "date"?

Answer (score 1):

There are two things you can do.

1. Create a new field with the following formula:

   SUM([cumulative value])-LOOKUP(SUM([cumulative value]),-1)

Tableau requires an aggregation for you to use the `LOOKUP` function.  Hence why I used the sum function.  Then you could plot that against `DAY(Date)`.

OR

2. Plot `DAY(Date)` against `SUM(cumulative value)`, then right click `SUM(cumulative value)`, click `Quick Table Calculation`, and then `Difference`.  This can only be used/done in plots though.